# Do IPv6 residential ISPs in Europe and North America typically give you a public subnet/delegation?

Tags: ipv6, isp

(I've searched around on Superuser but I couldn't find anything relevant)

I've never used a residential ISP that had IPv6 access[footnote1] so I don't know what the *typical* IPv6 customer experience is - so I had some questions about what I should expect when Wave does eventually support IPv6.

Presently with an IPv4 ISP (that doesn't employ "Carrier-grade" NAT), your router/gateway will be assigned a single "public" IPv4 address which is globally routable from any other node on the Internet. Because you get only a single IPv4 address rather, than a subnet assignment, you cannot give any computers or devices within your LAN network a publicly routable address, so your router has to be a NAT itself and you need to use private, non-routable addresses within your network, so to allow incoming connections from the Internet the best you can do is put them in [a DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) and/or use port-forwarding rules - assuming your router lets you do that.

(There are arguments for the use of NAT because it makes your computers unreachable from the Internet, so it's a kind of poor-man's-firewall - but that's another discussion)

With IPv6 - because there's no scarcity of IP addresses, it's possible for ISPs to assign each customer a large subnet - such as a 16-bit subnet allowing for ~65,000 hosts - which would all be directly routable addresses and so be directly accessible from any other Internet-connected host. Which means an end to NAT, and because any computer could then connect directly to any other we could, for example, run our own servers from home again.

But I couldn't find **any** information about residential ISPs in the US, Canada, or Western Europe about how IPv6-capable ISPs allocate IPv6 address space to their customers - or if the routers they provide to customers who choose to rent them are capable of acting as proper level 3 switch/router rather than just as a NAT gateway.

So my question is:

- If you have an IPv6 residential ISP, do they give you a single IPv6 address that you have to NAT (just like IPv4) - or do they give you a subnet?

  - If they give you a single address by default, can you still opt for a subnet?

    - And if you can opt for a subnet, how large an allocation can you request?
- How do you set-up routing on your router?
- Does their stock/rental router block all incoming connections and datagrams for IPv6 hosts by default?

---

#### Update

I found out why I wasn't finding anything relevant earlier - it's because in IPv6 the terminology is not "subnet" (which are always 64-bits long in IPv6), but instead the term is "[prefix delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_delegation)". When I search for that I'm able to find *some* answers to my question now, phew! But I'd still appreciate it if anyone could share their experiences.

---

[footnote1]: My ISPs in the UK were all ADSL LLU ISPs that couldn't even roll-out IPv6 even if they wanted to; while in the US I was a customer of Comcast before they rolled-out IPv6, and by the time they launched IPv6 I had already moved to a Wave Broadband area - and Wave's DOCSIS service is stuck on IPv4 for the forseeable future (Wave's [*WaveG* service *is* IPv6](https://waveg.wavebroadband.com/faq/#does-wave-g-support-ipv6)), but that's a separate service from their DOCSIS service).

Comment: Only the specific ISP can answer this question. As this is not about any infrastructure you have control over it is off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting collected information – I have only very briefly used IPv6 features on "home" routers. (I manage an IPv6 network at my workplace, but my home ISP has no plans for residential IPv6.)

> are capable of acting as proper level 3 switch/router rather than just as a NAT gateway.

Even in IPv4 world, most home NAT gateways *are* L3 routers – after the address translation is applied, they still follow a standard IP routing table. Most of them allow you to customize the routing table as you want, and disabling NAT still leaves you with a regular (if incredibly shitty) IPv4 router.

> With IPv6 - because there's no scarcity of IP addresses, it's possible for ISPs to assign each customer a large subnet - such as a 16-bit subnet allowing for ~65,000 hosts

That's not large. The recommended single subnet size is 64 bits (a /64 prefix), and the recommended residential prefix assignment is a /56 – giving you 72 bits to work with. (Recall that the total address length is 128 bits, so what you're describing is an /112.)

Every ISP is eligible for a /32 prefix *as their "starter pack"*, so they can easily afford a few million /64s.

> If you have an IPv6 residential ISP, do they give you a single IPv6 address that you have to NAT (just like IPv4) - or do they give you a subnet?

They give you a *prefix*, which is generally in the range of /56 to /64 depending on how lucky you are. (From what I've heard, /60 is common in USA.)

When using DHCPv6-PD, however, your router might not always acquire the maximum prefix you're allowed to have – e.g. with some ISPs, it might by default receive individual /64's unless it's configured to explicitly request a /60 in the IA_PD.

(And note that the router itself will still have a single address on the WAN side – that's a normal thing in any case, because the ISP will route your whole LAN prefix 'via' the router's WAN address.)

I have not heard of any ISPs which set up NAT masquerading. If that happened, it would be "fun" to hear them justify it, as they get plenty of address space to avoid it (even a beginning ISP can get a /29 prefix from RIPE, which is enough for 16 million /56's, or even two billion /60's).

> How do you set-up routing on your router?

I'd say there is almost nothing to "set up"... it already does routing, that's why it's a router. And it is actually not much different from IPv4 – routing tables and subnets work the same way, the ISP just doesn't impose NAT on you anymore.

Usually the DHCPv6-PD client will automatically assign subnets to your LAN interfaces, and will set up Router Advertisements to be sent. If you have a flat network with just 1 router, that's all there is.

> Does their stock/rental router block all incoming connections and datagrams for IPv6 hosts by default?

I haven't used many such routers, but from what I've heard, that's the most common case, yes.

> I found out why I wasn't finding anything relevant earlier - it's because in IPv6 the terminology is not "subnet" (which are always 64-bits long in IPv6), but instead the term is "prefix delegation".

The general term is "prefix" because **the emphasis is on addressing**, not on physical topology. Prefix delegation is the process by which your ISP assigns you an address prefix, usually via DHCPv6-PD.

A "subnet" would imply a specific topology (a single layer-2 domain), while a "prefix" can be divided up into whatever network layout and whatever internal routing you prefer, and it is possible for one network or subnet to have multiple prefixes as well (even in IPv4).

(For example, some manufacturers' routers will automatically set up a private ULA prefix for your LAN *alongside* the global ISP-provided prefix, so all your devices will have two IPv6 addresses – one from each prefix – while still being in a single subnet physically.)